# Dealing with an answer that wasn't accepted (maybe because a user is a newbie on Stack Overflow)

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette, new-users

I answered somebody's question. It was a new person who joined Stack Overflow today. He/she thanked me and said it works, but he/she hasn't accepted my answer.

The question is here for your reference: [Update Table in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164954/update-table-in-access/23166114#23166114).

Is it okay to send a comment telling him/her about how to accept answers, and maybe asking him/her to accept mine? Or should I just leave it, and maybe he/she will come back at some point in time?

I haven't been on Stack Overflow for long, so I too am a bit of a newbie and not sure about the etiquette.

Comment: You'll find a lot of variants of this question in MSE, e.g.: [Asking for someone to accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer)

Comment: Thank you... see how "newbie" I am? I didn't know about meta.stackexchange... Although now I realize meta.stackoverflow is brand new...By the way, should I delete my question or do anything with it now that you pointed me to answers in meta.stackexchange?

Comment: You don't need to do anything with this question, it's a legitimate question that hasn't been answered here yet AFAIK. Just wait a bit, I'm sure someone will share their view on this here, specifically in the context of Stack Overflow. (I'm too lazy to do that :-) )

Comment: Welcome to my world.  Only about 10% of my answers are accepted on the tags I'm active on.  I'm a well known expert in the subject with a 30K rating and it all comes from up votes because I'm always getting newbies who ask a question and then never accept the answer.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter At least you got a badge out of it?

Comment: @AleAssis Don't forget to accept one of the answers here ;) ...

Comment: What exactly is it that you (and maybe other people) dislike in an answer not being accepted?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with it, but I'll note that it looks pretty pathetic to me. I've never seen it done in a way that didn't sound like reputation begging and it always makes me feel a little dirty and sad.

Comment: Oh the Irony that his answer has been accepted on the original thread yet this remains "Unanswered". This has made my day!

Comment: I wish there was a "flag for acceptance" option for those times when the user has clearly accepted the answer by commenting.

Comment: Nevermind, my impression was obviously wrong. I can unmark an accepted answer and choose another later.

Comment: I hope I am not the only one seeing the irony in the fact that this question was asked a week ago and there still isn't an accepted answer.

Comment: @scott.korin  many months later...same irony

Comment: Irony noted here

Comment: yeah, it looks like revenge. The unAcceptables

Comment: Hi @AleAssis, did you find an answer to your question?  If any answer solved your question you can consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark (please don't though). This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.  There is no obligation to do this (definitely no obligation in this case).

Comment: I thought about PM'ing him on Twitter (@aleassis, found on his personal website linked on meta profile), but that would clearly conflict with the _"There is no obligation to do this"_ thing. =D

Comment: Holy... After all those years, there _IS_ an accepted answer. Mark your calendars guys. 26.08.2018 @6.23pm

Comment: For some reason I finally got a notification from Lafexlos comment and I do apologize for the ironic lack of acceptance of the answer :)

Comment: The suggestion of @MatheusMoreira in combination with a reminder/notification pop up or later message would be the best and easiest way to solve this. Some elementary analysis on comments for identifying terms like `thank you it worked`, `problem solved` etc could easily determine if there is a possible answer or not. Finally a discrete pop up with a message such as `Please don't forget to mark the answer if it solved your issue` I don't think it would put any sort of pressure to users in the contrary it would contribute to the smooth operation of SO and inform the new users

Comment: @AleAssis please change the accepted answer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417578/17242583, which reflects the mod's current advice.

Answer (score 444, accepted):

> **Note:** This answer is **no longer recommended or endorsed** by the moderation team. Please see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417578/584676) for more information.

If a *new* user has *never* accepted an answer before and has thanked you for your answer it is acceptable to point them to the functionality. I normally would write something like:

> Hi @user12345 if this or any answer has solved your question please
> consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419)
> by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider
> community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to
> both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

(original markdown):

`Hi @user12345 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.`

If the user has *ever* accepted an answer before or has been around for any amount of time then they're aware of how the system works. If you comment in this situation then it would normally appear as though you are either begging for reputation or pressurising a lower reputation user into accepting your answer - neither of which the community looks too kindly upon.

### tl;dr

It's okay. Once.

Comment: How about "Did you find my answer helpful, or do you need more help?" for low-reputation users who seem to have abandoned the question?

Comment: To be honest I wouldn't use the word _"my"_ @bjb568. If you're going down that route I'd write something like _"hi @ user12345, have the answers you've got fully answered your question? If they have [comment above] or if not can you [edit] your question to clarify why they haven't and include any missing information."_

Comment: This one-time limit would be reasonable if humans were robots, and you only needed to teach them something once for them to master the concept.  Humans aren't robots.  They often need to be instructed, and reminded multiple times.  Human programmers also juggle accounts on multiple programmer Q+A/forum sites.  Each may have different etiquette/rules.  Just because they got it right once, doesn't mean they won't lapse into their other forum habits.  If a programmer doesn't have a thick enough skin to handle a little nagging, my God, they're going to get killed in code reviews.

Comment: But that's part of the problem @Nate; what are you nagging about? You're nagging for someone to give you a little bit of rep. The one-time thing isn't much to do with the question asker, it's to protect the community and the question answerer

Comment: What about answers to questions where the users are now inactive? I've got one that I'd get an additional badge for but the user has been inactive for so long and never rewarded me with a tick, despite the fact it answers the question and is voted significantly higher than all other answers :(

Comment: @Ben You're not *only* nagging for rep. Marking a question as accepted also helps others that come across the question later. So while it might be self serving, it has other benefits.

Comment: It _might_ have other benefits @mason. There's no particular reason why the OP has more knowledge about the subject than the community and there are plenty of cases of completely wrong accepted answers. If I come across an answer to a question I'd normally try the one with the highest number of votes first.

Comment: I agree with this answer but not on the part where you say _[the user] has been around for any amount of time._ There are many users that register, ask a question, grab the answer and then disapper. They reappears after a long time (months, years?) ask a new question and leave agein. So the time parameter should not be considered if they have never accepted an answer.

Comment: If that's the case they haven't been "around" @Steve, they've been elsewhere... You could have a good guess from their act try as to which is is.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know a method to discover if a user has been  _around_ or not. I could talk of _active users_ or _lurkers_ (no offense intended) In any case I personally don't look at the seniority of registration but only to the fact that they never accepted answers or are new users. So I say: _Since you are a new user (or Since you are not a very active user) of this site I recommend to read [How To Accept Answers]_ .... then I could continue with your proposed comment

Comment: It would be helpful for other users to be able to "suggest an answer" to a post.

Comment: It's been suggested more times than you can imagine @the; the authoritative decline is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3669/179419

Comment: whats with the **BEGGING** thing, do you think after working a full 8 hours job daily for a full month or contributing to a freelance project, you don't get paid off timely and you ask the person to pay off is **begging** NO that's your right, I think it is unethical if someone continuously show up on a forum to ask for help and someone spares out some of his personal time to solve OP's problem, and OP doesnt even bothers to pay him off with some reputation points, thats more rude than asking someone in a nice way to mark any of the anwers posted that helped him out.

Comment: We can't completely prevent how we appear to others @Muhammad. Your intentions might be noble, but can be misinterpreted. If you don't want to write answers for people who don't accept answers, even though they know how to do it, you do have that option; you can look at their recent questions and see if they're in the habit of clicking the accept button and decide not to answer if you don't want to.

Comment: @Ben , yeah i agree that we can avoid answering on their question if we feel like, but then it would mean that others having the same problem might be suffering due to that person, that is what my intentions are contributing to stackoverflow, and i still answer the question, asking once might be OK, but not more than that, sorry if you found my comment rude in any way, was just discussing never ment to offend you or anyone else having different opinion. IDIOS

Comment: I didn't find your comment rude, though I suspect you're frustrated at the moment. It's perfectly okay to disagree with this answer as well @Muhammad. If you act on your disagreement you're more likely to end up in situations where other users (not necessarily the question asker) think you _are_ being rude. Like the rest of life, there's no right answer and it's up to you to work out what works for yourself and those around you (in this case complete strangers on the internet). I just hope that this little bit of advice has been helpful to someone at some point.

Comment: I've written a new answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417578/584676) with more details but this is no longer recommended and you may find yourself at odds with the moderation team if you continue to follow this advice today.

Answer (score 69):

I sometimes use standard verbiage to encourage a new user to accept an answer.  I use it very sparingly (these days) when I'm one contender among several, but will definitely use it when there's a 'Thanks' comment on someone else's answer and no acceptance, and sometimes when mine is the only answer.

If the advice has been followed, or is now moot because the user is not registered on Stack Overflow, or hasn't been seen for several years (yes, I mean years!) then I'll remove the comment when I next spot it.

Formatted:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow.
>   Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
>   up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
>   reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
>   question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
>   reputation).
>   Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
>   here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

In a comment, the `[About]` becomes a link.

Raw Markup:

```
Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
```

Comment: Or maybe `thanks` to [thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  lol

Answer (score 36):

In general, yes, you can post something. How exactly you word it depends on the asker.

For an inexperienced asker (based primarily on reputation, number of questions/answers, etc.), it is good etiquette to explain how to accept an answer and remind them to do so, always with the qualifier of "if it answers your question." If there are many answers, you might consider commenting on the question itself and wording it to encourage them to accept *an* answer, rather than yours.

If the user is more experienced, a different approach is required as they already know all this. Chances are they just forgot to accept an answer. In this case, I start by waiting a while. A couple days, usually. After some time has passed, I ask if one of the proposed answers sufficiently answers their question or if they still have a problem. I usually also ask for them to provide some clarification or to elaborate if the answers don't work for them. This kind of comment serves a triple purpose: 1) It reminds them to accept an answer, without being rude. 2) It asks if any of the answers work, which is useful information for anyone else viewing the question. 3) It prompts them to provide additional details if the answers don't work, giving everyone who answered a chance to revise their answers or for the OP to post their own answer if they figured it out on their own. This all works toward one end goal: providing a full answer to the question that is clearly marked for other users having a similar problem. I have yet to have anyone respond negatively to such a comment.

In short: You can generally find some polite way of addressing the lack of an accepted answer in a comment. Don't be pushy. Assume the OP knows what they're doing, unless it is clearly a new user. If it's clearly a new user, you can provide brief instructions on how the site works.

Answer (score 20):

I have always said something, regardless of their status. What's the harm? Worst case they already know and just accept at a later time.

Comment: It's rude, that's the harm.

Comment: @Servy lol, I didn't know people had such touchy feelings on here

Comment: It's rude, and sometimes will get your answer downvotes from those who think so - especially if the badgering-for-accept is posted quickly (or even in the answer itself) or on an answer with isn't of very high quality to begin with.

Comment: What?! Surely its rude to ask people for help and ignore their effort afterwards.

Comment: @Servy ,  I think it is unethical if someone continuously show up on a forum to ask for help and someone spares out some of his personal time to solve OP's problem, and OP doesnt even bothers to pay him off with some reputation points, thats more rude than asking someone in a nice way to mark any of the anwers posted that helped him out, but i think these are manners, i always accepted the answer right from the start when i joined, If you are by nature not a thankless person you will always remember who helped you in your bad time, and will always be thankfull.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam You appear to be answering questions because you care about Imaginary Internet Points, rather than because you want to contribute to creating a useful repository of knowledge. Going around accepting answers because you feel compelled to "pay people off" rather than because you simply want to indicate what answer was most helpful to you, *hurts* the ability of the site to be that useful repository of knowledge. Prioritizing reputation and your own recognition over being helpful isn't something many people are interested in doing, and it makes you look rude in the process.

Comment: @Servy i never said that I would contact the person again or be rude with him in process of getting the answer accepted, what I said that there isn't any harm to say **ONCE**, you noticed about paying off people but you forgot that I mentioned about being thankful too. So you are **JUDGING** about **WHY** i contribute, yes I do care about the reputation points to some extent as it shows to the community that I am contributing a fair amount, and i dont like to be an **UN-SUNG hero** it aint a war going on dude.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yes, there *is* harm in trying to badger people into accepting answers, rather than letting them accept the answers they naturally choose to when they decide *on their own*, to mark an answer as helpful.  I'm judging your motivations because it's *harming others* to prioritize reputation over helping others.

Comment: @Servy dude, you ARE touchy, asking once isn't badgering, badgering means **To persuade someone through constant annoying efforts**, once is OK, thats all what i meant to say, just look into my answers i have alot of answers posted for new comers although they were about to be closed for being too broad, if they dont accept it even being the right one,i would still add an answer next time if they post, atleast it can help others having the same problem, i dont mean to harm anyone feelings over here, everyone has different opinion, i cant judge others for being different than me. IDIOS

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam So now you're saying you are frequently posting answers to questions that are too broad, and merit closure appropriately?  That's a whole new problem.  But when all of a person's questions result in comments by people demanding to have their answers accepted, and who consider someone not accepting an answer to be rude, as you are demonstrating is  your opinion here, and when they see that behavior on the questions of others that they see, it absolutely comes off as badgering.

Comment: nopes, i said that in context to the intent of helping others not just looking for reputation points, even if i know the guy hasnt been able to narrow down the problem being a new bee to programming or SO, i would still help them out, they accept or not i would just ask them once after a week or so, if they dont accept i wont bother again, dude chill out, having a different opinion doesnt mean the other person is wrong, you are constantly trying to do that just to prove your point, and what i just described isnt badgering at all or what i said in my previous comment, chill.

Answer (score 19):

If **I** answer a question and the OP never accepts any answer, I usually just **don't do anything**. However, if I come across a question that:

1. Was asked some time ago, *and*
2. I did not place an answer on, *and*
3. Has an answer that does address the problem

Then, I **leave a comment** reminding the asker to accept an answer and I might even hint that one of the given answers does address his issue.

Comment: you can do the same for yours too, reminding someone once after posting an answer, lets say after 7 days and you dont see any update or replies from the person you can ask the person in a nicer way if he is still facing the problem and wasnt able to solve, i almost have around 25 answers where i posted a comment after more than a month in the same way and the OP accepted it right away with an apology, and alot of them never replied back, i leave them alone.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Apparently there's a risk of looking rude doing it for your own although I feel that risk is overblown.  If we all get in the habit of issuing reminders for each other, we mitigate that risk.

Comment: @John, yes there is a risk until we choose the correct words or approach, rather than forcing the person to accept the answer, i would ask the person if he wasn't able to solve the problem yet so i can help out, that mostly gets the answer accepted if the problem was solved and if the user checks in frequently otherwise i won't ask him a second time.

Answer (score 16):

I always point new users to this if they do not accept an answer of mine on which they commented it solved their problem.

I do this by pointing to the fact accepting an answer **indicates the question is resolved and that the chosen answer is validated as working**. Hence, you won't be wasting the time of people who are:

1. Looking to answer **unresolved** questions
2. Looking for validated answers

It makes it more difficult to look for good questions *and* answers when they're not marked as accepted, so I try to explain this to new users. Something along the lines of:

> Glad the solution worked. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people experiencing a similar issue and will help getting your question noticed. For more information, take a look at our [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks and welcome to SO!

Original mark down:

```
Glad the solution worked. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people
experiencing a similar issue and will help getting your question noticed. For more
information, take a look at our [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks and welcome to SO!
```

I agree you should comment in sucha way on experienced users, they know how the system works (hopefully (:) and spamming these comments will make you look like you're begging for reputation.

There's one exception though, and that is users with low accept rate. To me, it makes perfectly sense to keep on trying to educate them. You don't even have to do this for your own answers, if you spot an unresolved question, which has an answer that should be the accepted one, simply point this out to the OP.

**Avoid spamming these comments**, if someone's not willing, it simply won't happen.

Comment: I'm not sure about this comment... why your answer and not anyone else's? Acceptance also won't help people with a similar issues, your answer will do that. It won't help with getting the question noticed either - and this is beside the point for someone who's just got a working answer.

Comment: I only ever add it when the OP indicated (in comments) it helped him/her with his/her problem. I'm not spamming this around on every answer I provide :). Acceptance indicates very clearly the question was resolved. I'm not saying acceptance is always a measure for a good quality answer (there are countless examples out there), I just know when I'm looking for answers my first focus will be on questions that have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 16):

While [Ben's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251298/584676) was once considered the correct behavior on the site, site features since his answer was posted have improved and users are now encouraged in-application to accept or upvote answers. As such, the mod team [no longer endorses](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417570/blatantly-unprofessional-behavior-by-a-moderator-with-no-accountability#comment905718_41757) the practice of encouraging users, however new to the site they may be, to accept answers or vote in either direction via post comments.

It is actually [now considered a violation of community rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417573/584676) and may draw the ire of the moderation team if this type of engagement continues, so while there is a historical appreciation of Ben's answer, following its advice today may get you in some trouble. **Do not use the comment sections to encourage or otherwise nudge users towards accepting answers or voting, as the site functionality covers this today.**

This answer is not an endorsement of these rules, but rather, a signpost as to what the moderator expectations in this case are as it starkly juxtaposes the highest-voted-and-accepted answer here.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you do so, but i would be good to see a revision of the (currently) accepted answer; which has a much large number of (up)votes compared to other answers on this post. In truth, perhaps a FAQ type question would be better, which can be used as a canonical in the future/

Comment: I did consider that, but I felt a new answer would be a good entrypoint to the matter without making a unilateral edit to a highly upvoted Meta answer. I am still fairly new in engaging with meta at the level I have been lately and don't want to overstep. But honestly, I feel this question and its accepted answer make excellent candidates as a community wiki so that it may be updated as the site and the moderation team positions change, and not necessarily owned by a single poster.

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested that perhaps a FAQ question be created (again, not suggesting you do); clearly the position of the moderators has changed (I can't speak for the community), but the current accepted answer (by status and score) reflect the old position and there's no information to denote that it has. It would be better if a moderator made the current position known. I don't think editing the answer current accepted answer to change the stance is correct; it should be noted in the answer it is outdated and link to the new stance.

Comment: Before doing that I'd like to see what Cody or another mod responds with to my comment in the other thread where I ask what the mod team would prefer we do in the case their position clashes with previously established norms they-themselves have recommended in the past.

Comment: Agreed, I did ask if the answer would be edited in those comments, but they are yet to respond.

Comment: As [your comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on/417578#comment905744_251298) under the accepted answer is the 17th, it's very easy to miss. You might consider editing a pointer to this answer into the accepted one.

Comment: Hi - I'm in agreement with the original goal of Stack Exchange. Please edit my answer to make Cody's comment clear and change the emphasis. Cerberus' answer deals with a different topic and doesn't appear to answer this question as asked.

Comment: I've community wikied the answer, even though I get no rep to make this more palatable.

Comment: @Ben I've added a redirection to this answer to preserve the original intent of the outdated answer. I have also community wiki'd this answer as well.

Comment: Given that the top answer is accepted and is a community wiki (and considering revision history is a thing available to everyone), we should probably delete this answer and just edit the top/accepted answer, instead.

Comment: @TylerH Is there no value in preserving the original answer as it was? If the answers are as contrasted as they are then the feedback on the original answer become largely irrelevant, as the feedback was directed towards completely different content. Also note that Ben and I converted our answers to community wikis at about the same time.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Not if it's a FAQ that people point to and it's wrong. If people want to know what it used to say, they can look at the revision history.

Comment: @TylerH I still feel separating the original answer and the new answer is relevant for preserving the original answer's intent, especially since the original advice was well-received on its own. The new recommendation should be able to be evaluated on its own merits without being boosted by feedback of the prior content. That's the point of a Q&A format isn't it? New answers should be presented as just that, new answers, rather than repurposing an old one when the content changes drastically. That's my two cents anyways. The fact that it's now wrong is addressed in the edit.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest For normal Q&A, yes. For Meta FAQ, no, what's important is that users see the right content immediately/always.

Comment: I do not understand the reasoning for this at all.  New users need to be trained in the ways of the site and an appropriately worded comment can help them understand the process on the site in many ways (not just in this way).  Whatever stuff the site thinks it is showing the user, it VERY often doesn't work.  The emphasis should be on the attitude and style of the communication, not on there being no communication on the topic at all.  Where is this "rule" written down?   Or did some moderators just take this up on their own and decide this is the way it should be?

Comment: That's the whole point, @jfriend00 - *accepting* answers is not the way of the site these days. This has been proven to be detrimental to the site in the long run, and [even the company realized that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/11407695) - encouraging users to do something that is bad for the site but still is legacy allowed is not a good idea. As for voting, it seems that the benefits of reminding new users to vote do not outweigh the issue of abusing i to ask users to vote not for *any* answer, but for the answer of the user posting the comment gave from the moderator team POV.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - First, I ask where the actual written rule is or is this just what a few moderators now think?  Second, I restate my objection to banning ALL communication on the topic.  There are plenty of styles of communication that would be beneficial to both the site and to the OP so the emphasis should be on what styles are appropriate and what are not rather than banning any discussion of it at all.  Just look at your last sentence.  It implies that because some abuse it, we must ban all forms of it.  Why not just decide what is and isn't appropriate rather than banning all?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - Since you want to prevent me from helping to educate new users on the ways of the site in any way, this is making me consider whether I may just stop engaging with questions from new users with no history of understanding how the site works.   FYI, in the 13,293 answers I've provided in almost 11 years, I've never once seen any objection to coaching a new user on how the site works (either from the OP or from a mod) and I've certainly helped thousands of new users to understand the ways of the site better than they did before.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - And, how is "accepting" a best answer not the way of the site any more?  When did that change?  Why is the feature still there, then?  Your link is about not pinning the best answer to the top and nothing else.

Comment: @jfriend00 the feature still here because it takes the company 6 to 8 to do *anything*. Besides, a *complete* removal is something worthy of a wider community discussion regardless, no one is arguing for that here. What changed is 
the consensus on *encouraging* to accept *an* answer (the OP is the least qualified person to determine what answer is "best"). Re: post - please look at the findings strongly implying that "acceptance" heavily biases voting patterns towards the accepted answer regardless of quality.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - The exact same bias happens on the most upvoted answer.  The answer with the most upvotes is more likely to get more upvotes.  And, newer answers that may even have more complete or more up-to-date info in them are very unlikely to get many upvotes.  So, are you going to get rid of upvotes for the same reason.  This place is going nuts.  For myself, my main point of writing answers is to compete for the psychic reward of winning the best answer competition.  I do this for my own entertainment and that's a significant part of why I participate.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - I don't do anything nefarious to try to win that "best answer" competition.  I just try to produce the best possible answer.  And, I'm pretty good at it.  So, now you're saying that the site may be eliminating that?  And, they are already de-emphasizing it?

Comment: @jfriend00 if you feel like you do not want to engage with questions from new users unless they "prove" their worth, feel free to do so. How many contributions you made so far is orthogonal to the discussion at hand. If the moderator team felt like your comment patterns are problematic, you would've received a warning (like [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417570/11407695) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415702/11407695)).

Comment: @jfriend00 funny you mention upvoting bias! FYI, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416486/11407695) is another project currently in the works that *specifically* targets this exact issue (which does, indeed, exist)."this place" is not going nuts, it finally deals with inherent problems with both voting and accepting that became apparent with the enormous scale SO has presently.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - Now, I'm totally confused as to what is and isn't OK.  Because I've never been slapped on the hand by a moderator for my practices, you're saying these practices are likely not being seen as a problem?  For the third time, is there a written policy for this that is not just some opinions here in meta or some opinions by some current moderators?  I mention the level of my contributions here just to define my level of experience on the site and to provide that context to my feedback.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - I mention questions from new users for several reasons.  First off, they need the most help in learning how to write a good question.  Second, they need the most coaching on editing questions to add clarification, on not just disappearing for days at a time when people have engaged and are trying to help, on communicating when their problem has been solved or not solved yet, etc....  If the site implements policies that make it less likely for experienced SO users to engage with new users, I would think that's not good for the site as a whole.

Comment: Re: warning - they were either seen as generally harmless to let it go or no one just got to it, I cannot speak for the moderator team. A good analogy here, though, is crossing a road not on a pedestrian crossing: 99% of the time, no one notices but that 1% of the time, someone does, and you get fined. This is why I say that mentioning that you haven't been slapped on the wrist *yet*, however many contributions, is relevant. That also isn't saying that you *will*. What's in discussion here is whether this behavior is to be *encouraged* by a prominent Meta post.

Comment: The problem with improving *in-built* ways of teaching new users how to engage with the site properly when asking questions is curently being worked on in another recent project - the [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416428/introducing-the-staging-ground-an-attempt-at-improving-the-first-time-asker-exp), btw.

Comment: I think what jfriend is asking for is a post or something overriding the canonical answer from a moderator, saying the policy has changed. Right now it seems like a 180 to them as well as several others on the site. I myself have mixed feelings here because I don't disagree with the new direction, but there has also been zero communication from the mod team about the policy changing from suddenly getting slapped on the wrist for previously allowed and recommended behavior. *Experiments* around sorting and updating outdated answers don't preclude written rules about expected decorum.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest the policy "change" isn't exactly *sudden*, see [my comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415702/is-it-okay-to-request-a-newbie-user-to-accept-and-upvote#comment892513_415702) here showing that it's never been particularly popular amogst the moderator team (with links to Meta answers). However, a caveat has been kept that it is a "harmless" excercise provided the author of the comment does not make a significant number of such comments on their posts, this is just a matter of making it clear that posting those at all should not be "encouraged" in any way.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - Where is this "policy change" written down?  I'd like to read it.  I've asked several times and you and others have not responded with a link to any specific document of the policy.  That makes me think this is just some momentum thing among a few moderators.  Is that how site policies are made here?  How are such site policies communicated to the general public when they change?

Comment: @jfriend00 I cannot speak about the others, but I tried to respond to your comments in order, and due to sheer number of followups and 4AM for me could not get to it. I don't think there is a written one apart from several mod responses over the years that do not condone this (I linked them in my replies to Bender above, though). To be honest, in general, there are no written down mod policies apart from a couple of cases (e.g. deletion of a post under Meta discussion), and I agree with you this is unfortunate and with Bender that it would be nice to see an "official" policy written down.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine - OK, I guess you agree that's an issue.  Some moderators are attempting to change a long history of how things are done, but there is no written policy and I (and presumably other long running, active users) have received no communication about such policy changes.  That seems to a recipe for confusion..

Comment: Wow, how unfortunate. When I look for answers, accepted ones get my immediate attention, and when I post answers getting them accepted is a reward and encouragement. I would have thought moderators would want to encourage anything that increased the rate of marking good answers. This change makes the site significantly less useful to me. It would be nice to know how each moderator stands on this issue for the next round of voting.

Comment: @RobertSheahan acceptance does not mean quality at all, it only means helpfulness to the author of the question, which is orthogonal to quality. Also of note is that moderator positions are *for life*, there are no reelections (except for a corner-case).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine, in my experience accepted answers may not *equate* to quality but they *correlate* well, and thus are not orthogonal, but either way they get my attention first. Thanks for the info on moderators.

Comment: @RobertSheahan correlation is orthogonal to causation, though. Accepted answers, by definition, are the ones that helped the author most - it might or might not indicate quality, which is exactly the point. Re: mods - speaking of corner cases, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75192/786798) FAQ MSE post might be of interest.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Yes, correlation and causation are orthogonal, which means a lack of causation does not imply a lack of correlation. We don't care about causality, only if answers that help the original poster are better than average and therefore worth correctly identifying. I want to know if an answer solved the stated problem, and SO would be more useful to me if they did a better job identifying those answers.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, I do agree that the lack of written down explicit moderation policies is quite an oversight stemming from the old days where not as huge as these days. If I have time, hopefully, I am going to motion for a policy to be established in a formal manner. I do also agree that we all benefit from having such things stated in a form that allows one to be sure they are not getting tripped by a rule or a change they haven't been aware of.

Comment: I understand and respect the discussion so far, and while frustrated by no formal policy, it can shift. I find at least one statement in this answer proven insufficient over time: *"encouraged in-application to accept or upvote answers"*. I'm glad to see better recommendations and hints during question-asking. However, empirically (in my experience), they are still too-often ignored. If it were enough, then the rate of first-askers accepting answers would go up; I don't have a query to support it, but I've not felt a change. Is there a SEDE query that informs this? I'd like to be wrong here.

Comment: Some people just are not aware of the voting system, which is usually clear from the user question history. This should be allowed to point such users to guidelines instead of their spamming with "thank you", "i am grateful" and suchlike comments. It is not at all the same as asking for upvotes. Moderators are at a great fault here.

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely do something like that.  The user may simply be unaware of SO guidelines and/or etiquette.  A fundamental assumption that you as the answer-giver have to work with though is that there are some people who:

1. Have a problem
2. Sign up for SO
3. Ask their question
4. Get their answer
5. Leave without ever being heard from again or sign up for a new account when they have a new problem.

That is part of the "risk" of using you time to answer a question.  There is no mechanism for the community or moderators (that I am aware of) to retroactively assign best answers based upon this scenario.

Comment: There is no mechanism, no. It's been rejected multiple (read hundreds) of times. Acceptance doesn't even indicate that an answer is the "best"; that's what your votes are for (and why they're so important). Acceptance only indicates that this was the answer which helped the OP the most.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like there's something wrong with asking someone to accept *your* answer. That seems a bit pretentious.

I think its OK to ask them to accept some answer. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a Q site.

I've even been in situations where I land on Stack Overflow in an unfamiliar area and I have to ask "what's wrong with Answer X since you did not accept it (or any others). It seems OK to me, but I don't know the technology".

You can also cite [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). I often do it to nudge a new user and help him/her learn how to use the site.

Answer (score -4):

I think the following can be a possible solution:

New users should automatically receive a message that welcomes them and gives them information about Stack Overflow's "recommended rules of etiquette", if they can be called that, or points them towards useful resources or answers that clarify these. Perhaps [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) can do this by automatically sending a message to new users which tells them to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

This could potentially reduce the amount of questions about what new users should or should not do.

The "recommended rules of etiquette" can be guidelines for the "recommended behaviour", if it can be called that, that is expected on Stack Overflow.

Comment: We already try to have new users take the [tour] and that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Codeer, I have just received the "Informed" badge by reading the entire tour page. Why was I not told about the tour when I became a new user? Do existing users expect new users to already know about the tour?

Comment: I can't answer that for you. I do know that users tend to link to the tour page when they stumble upon new users, but most of the time new users just skim the page so (some) people just... give up trying to do so.

Comment: We also put quite a bit of information in front of new users before their first post.  Even one where they have to click, "Yes, I have read this and understand".  And they still don't get it right.  Users don't read.  You can't make them; they actively ignore and bypass everything that doesn't relate to accomplishing their goal, which is to get an answer to their problem.

Comment: @fbueckert, if new users "actively ignore and bypass everything that doesn't relate to accomplishing their goal, which is to get an answer to their problem", shouldn't they deserve to face the ensuing consequences?

Comment: You'd think so; it only makes sense to try to familiarize yourself with a site before trying to use it.  But apparently the vast majority of new users just think we're hostile, because they have a problem, and we're being mean when we don't help them.  Just search meta for, "hostility"; dollars to donuts it's a new user that doesn't like their crappy question got closed or downvoted.

Comment: @fbueckert, I think new users should be informed of the information you have provided in order to change the way they perceive existing users and the community in general. How can that be done effectively though?

Comment: That's a thorny issue; most of it comes from properly setting expectations, I feel.  We've got a test of the new question wizard which will help, but how much is up for debate.  Those expectations need to be set *before* they can post their problem; doing it after the fact means it'll just be ignored.  So if the system can indicate that their question will get a rough reception, and are they sure they want to post it gets a confirmation, well, they know going in it's bad.  We'll never completely eliminate complaints, but expecting veterans to onboard all new users just isn't working.

Answer (score -7):

Reminding users, regardless of their status, to accept and/or upvote *answers that help them* is in the best interest of the question asker, the question answerer, S.O., and the community at large.

Reminders do need to contain the qualification of 'helpful', it's counterproductive to upvote or accept bad or useless answers, and they shouldn't be repeated for any given question, but within that limit reminders are a strong net positive.

Voting/accepting answers has two main functions, it helps users looking at existing questions evaluate the answer(s), and it helps motivate users to post answers through gamification. Gamification works. It's used successfully in numerous situations including language learning applications, fitness, etc., and S.O. knows this. Both of these functions work best when there is a high percentage of question askers using them, and reminders (not nagging, but tactful reminders) improve this rate.

For the question asker, the reminder gives them a chance to earn a small amount of reputation, to feel a part of the community, and helps keep them from gaining a reputation as a sponge. It also encourages question answerers to take a risk on users without a history of accepting answers.

Some answers take considerable work to develop, and a low accept rate from new users exerts pressure on some potential answerers to focus on questions from users with a track record of accepting answers. It certainly won't stop all answers to questions from new askers, but it will exert a downward pressure.

For the question answer, the reminder improves the chance of getting reputation, feedback, and a thank you. This keeps answerers engaged and active. Not everyone is motivated equally, but it's foolish to artificially shrink the pool of potential answerers.

For S.O., reminders increase the use of the voting system, which they clearly put in on purpose. It generates more traffic in numerous ways including askers are encouraged to return and vote, answerers feel more rewarded and participate more, and users and answerers get notifications which they check up on. It also makes the site more useful because viewers can more easily identify useful answers, and it makes the site appear more active and therefore more relevant.

For the community at large, reminders encourage more acceptance/voting and therefore they can better tell what answers are good answers. If most askers accept and/or vote on answers, then an answer without votes or acceptance is  likely to be low quality, but if most askers don't vote then searchers have to spend more effort evaluating each potential answer.

Obviously reminders can be taken too far and become nags that drive users off or pressure them to accept bad answers, but answers can be bad too and we don't ban answers in general just because they might be abused, we'd have no S.O. if we did that. Allowing and even encouraging tasteful reminders is a win for all involved.

Many sites, including Microsoft, allow answers to include reminders in their posts or even their signatures, and S.O. should do so as well, and should even reject edits that remove tasteful reminders.

Comment: The first thing I want to do when I see someone begging for accepts/votes from the Question author is downvote. The second thing I want to do is put a link to the most upvoted Answer on this post, which basically says "Don't beg for reputation points".

Comment: *Informing* a new member about accepting, as described in Ben's answer, is fine. Soliciting for votes is not ok. And anyway, it's pointless to ask new members for votes because they don't have enough rep to cast votes. Presumably, once they've earned enough rep to vote they can make their own voting decisions without needing reminders. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring Note that it is [no longer okay](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417578/584676)

Comment: @Bender Thanks for that info. I hope that an appropriate FAQ (or equivalent) gets created. In the meantime, I've upvoted your linked answer, but I'll wait to see the FAQ before deleting my comment to Robert. I must admit that I'm somewhat surprised by this apparent change of policy. FWIW, a prominent SO mod has posted numerous "how to accept" comments (via a userscript), but I don't know if he still does that.

Comment: You are not the only one. I don't even disagree with the new guideline, but the moderator position on this issue seems to have done a 180. I certainly didn't know anything had changed around guiding new members towards the upvote and answer accept policy. Ben's original answer on this question has been ***the*** canonical reference for dealing with users who don't accept answers since 2014. Seeing prominent members of the site admonished for following the canonical advice is very concerning. There needs to be better communication from mods to the community when their policies change.

Comment: Frankly, I don't see the harm in a purely educational comment that links to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234 and doesn't try to beg or coerce. I've posted such comments on other people's good answers, not just my own, and also on the question itself, eg "If an answer below has helped you, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/334566) it". And I only do it if the OP is very new, or if they've asked a dozen or so questions with virtually no accepts despite having received numerous good answers.

Comment: OTOH, I have no hesitation in flagging comments that blatantly beg or pester the OP for a vote or accept.