# The SO should notify the upvotes at least if it's given by the person who has asked the question

Tags: feature-request, upvotes, notifications

It's been a week since I've joined SO, and find it very irritating to see all my efforts to be in vain. The problem is that sometimes all you get is an upvote for the correct answer (sometimes not even that), while there is still no acceptance of answer by the question asker. SO should notify the answerer of the upvotes at least if it's given by the person who has asked the question. This way we at least would know if it really helped the person who asked the question. Or an even better approach would be to notify the person who posted the question to mark the answer as 'accepted' if he is upvoting an answer without accepting any other answer also.

**Edit** 
Now reading the title of my post again, I guess its misleading.. What I really wanted to convey was that if I answer something and I get an upvote on it, then if that upvote is from the question asker, I should be notified about it also. If its upvoted by someone else, then its ok to simply notify +10 reputation or whatever.. I hope it makes more sense now...

Comment: "Or rather better approach is to notify this person who posted the question to mark the answer as 'accepted' if he is upvoting an answer without accepting any other answer too" - done. We just added this feature :) In fact we're so thoughtful we added it before you even asked for it.

Comment: I hvnt posted any question so far.. So maybe that's why I didn't know about it.. But the fact that many questions (with correct solution ofcourse) go with unaccepted answers makes one think that such a feature is definitely lacking as the question asker is just upvoting the answer without actually accepting it..

Comment: Well it's not lacking. Now you know.

Comment: @sashoalm, can you elaborate? I find no trace of that feature in the [recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/164403).

Comment: Yup.. But why not have the feature mentioned in the title of this question? At least the answer submitter should know whether his answer really helped the question asker or not..

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I've upvoted questions and this tooltip appears - "have you considered accepting?" or something like that.

Comment: Also, related: [Dealing with an answer that wasn't accepted (maybe because a user is a newbie in SO)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251288/464709).

Comment: How do you even know if it's the op who upvotes? Many people dump and run and never look back. Or get notifications in email and don't visit again.

Comment: @sashoalm, now I don't understand. Why would a *have you considered accepting?* tooltip appear when you upvote a *question*?

Comment: +1 @MichaeIT .. You are so correct.. This is so disheartening for the contributors..

Comment: And this is so amazing.. The moment someone sees a downvote on a question, everybody jumps in to downvote without even thinking once.. Looks like we have a series of smart followers/ copy-pasters in here.. *annoying*

Comment: @SaurabhRajpal Voting is different on meta. In a feature request, people downvote to say they don't want the feature. It's not against you, and it doesn't affect your reputation :) no worries there

Comment: @Patrice thanks for focusing on the fist line of my post.. ' Its been a week that I've joined SO.' :) but seriously the concern is not the reputation but getting the credit for the efforts being put in..

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Sorry, I meant to say an answer to one of my own questions. My mistake.

Comment: Now reading the title of my post again, I guess its misleading.. What I really wanted to convey was that if I answer something and I get an upvote on it, then if that upvote is from the question asker, I should be notified about it too.. If its upvoted by someone else, then its ok to simply notify +10 reputation or whatever.. I hope it makes more sense now...

Comment: @SaurabhRajpal I'm not sure you have enough of a rationale to support adding this feature. How would it help users? What does it matter who upvoted your post? If the OP considered it useful they will upvote/accept it. If not, there's nothing you can do unless they give you a comment explaining why they did not. They're already prompted to upvote/accept useful things. All this would do is cause more people to leave comments like "OP you upvoted my answer, why didn't you accept it?" That's just noise.

Comment: "OP you just upvoted my answer, why didn't you accept it?" Exactly my point.. In my view if OP upvoted your answer and hasn't accepted any other answer too, that means the answer definitely helped him.. But still he hasn't accepted the answer.. Weird right? Also, if someone else upvoted you, it simply means he agrees to your solution and reemphasize to OP that he should rather give it a try (if he still hasn't)..

Comment: @SaurabhRajpal sure weird, but not up to you. OP's already been prompted to accept an answer, for whatever reason they chose not to. It's not up to you to goad an asker into accepting your answer. When I see comments like that I promptly flag them for deletion because they are annoying and useless to the site.

Comment: @eddie_cat first of all thanks a lot for watching your language and changing tone from 'none of your business' to 'not up to you'.. Secondly, there are many OP who simply get their work done and move on without even acknowledging the efforts being put in to help.. If getting credit for right efforts is also wrong, then I rest my case.. You can flag all my comments too as you are so great at it.. _/\_

Comment: I don't know what those lines at the end of my comment are.. Ignore it as a typo rather than jumping onto some conclusions.. Thanks!

Comment: So what will you do with the nofication? How is it relevant information for you and what would a subsequent action be?

Comment: Nobody has noticed that the OP is voting on his own posts?  It is up to him.

Comment: @Bart : I'll apparently create more noise as pointed out by Eddie_cat..

Comment: Listen, I'm trying to draw out a constructive argument in favour of the proposed feature. If you don't have one, I guess my vote is clear.

Comment: Say what @HansPassant?

Comment: Noyhing against you @Bart.. The harsh comments/tone like 'none of your business' is kind of irritating.. I don't think we should suppress someone's opinion like this.. My intent was to get 'accept rate'  to increase.. No matter how its addressed, but its definitely a concern..

Comment: @SaurabhRajpal People telling you that they don't think your proposal is a good idea and expressing their opinion that it would only cause problems isn't "suppressing your opinion".  Suppressing your opinion would be just deleting the question without responding to it.

Comment: @Servy I respect people responding.. I was particularly unhappy at the language and tone used by some people.. That's it.. No hard feelings.. :)

Comment: @SaurabhRajpal The only person I'm seeing comments from in an unconstructive tone is you.  It sounds like you're reading the comments in the tone that you think is unconstructive just because they're telling you things you didn't want to hear.  Most of them are actively trying to help you flesh out your proposal and you're treating them as hostile.

Comment: Sentences like 'none of your business' is definitely harsh.. At least not soothing I would say.. Anyways, Sincere apologies to anyone who feel I was harsh and used bad tone.. No more comments from my side.. Sorry for such a bad enhancement request (with positive intent from my side though)

Comment: @SaurabhRajpal you said it yourself that the "none of your business" comment was removed. In fact I edited it seconds after posting because I thought perhaps it sounded harsh. Not sure why you are still bringing it up.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need for you to know where an upvote comes from, not even if it's from the OP.

If they value what you have posted, but it didn't fully answer their concerns, they can already tell you. If they don't, that's their loss.

The last thing we need however is for users to badger the OP into accepting their answer. "If you upvoted my answer, why didn't you accept it?" is not the kind of content we need on the site. It's not exactly the same as the whole ["accept rate" issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate), but I foresee a similar outcome.

Comment: Its not about badgering the OP to accept the answer.. Its about stop following your answers to see if you could really be of any help to OP.. When I know my answer has got an upvote from someone else but not OP then I can still extend my help to him by engaging in a chat maybe or by any other means..

Comment: Let the OP pull you into that with a comment. (And only if the OP isn't a help vampire). That's the right way round. You may not abuse the information, but in the general case I don't see your request resulting in something positive.