# Encourage acceptance of correct answers

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Although not always a problem, I have noted that it seems to be happening more.

What that is, is that a poster has clearly seen the answer (as they have replied to it) and has stated that it has worked for them.
Yet, they do not accept the answer.

This is not a question to "Encourage users to accept answers" quickly. But rather that they should accept the answer. If plain to see has worked for them.

If the answer works, but there is a separate issue with the problem outside the original question, then a new question must be asked and the provided answer accepted.

Yes, this is a free forum, but it is like getting someone to solve your problem for you and not paying them.

What I propose is to add something to the system.
A `flag` of some kind to show that the user is a free loader.
Harsh perhaps, but I am open to other ideas as well.

So then if the user is seen to have (say 4 or more), then they are stopped from asking questions. Then they must ask a moderator to lift the ban.

What do you all think?

EDIT:
Although [THIS question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on)  as pointed out raises the same issue, I am not asking the same question. People really need to read through things better.

Also please note that I am not looking for a "forceful" or "required to answer" from a user. But rather as stated, to encourage polite use of the site.

As well as the "flag" idea would not display to everyone that it has been used. Only to the user in question as such time they have four or more questions that have flag's on them.

Comment: We had a metric called [acceptance rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work) in the past, you should research what happened with it. It [didn't work out so well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate).

Comment: @RobertLongson , I am not looking to "shame" or have it public as a way to "forcefully encourage" a user. But rather in the back. But the system cant READ that it was accepted by the user but not physically ACCEPTED by them. So a moderator ( I think ) is needed to assist.

Comment: I suggest that a comment containing things like "thanks" or "that solved my problem" make a dialog box show up asking the user if they want to accept the answer.

Comment: We have like a dozen moderators, and 12,000+ new questions every day. It's not a task humans could handle even if they should. There already are strong automated hints that you can mark an answer as accepted; that should be enough. The accept mark isn't that important anyway.

Comment: @gnat . I see the similarities, but I think that this is not about asking, but rather adding to the system..

Comment: @Donald Duck, that might go to helping, but not solve it. @ Pekka , moderator only is needed if the user request to be allowed to post questions again

Comment: [top answer over there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251298/839601) seem to directly explain that the way you want is wrong: "...If the user has _ever_ accepted an answer before or has been around for any amount of time then they're aware of how the system works. If you comment in this situation then it would normally appear as though you are either begging for reputation or pressurising a lower reputation user into accepting your answer - neither of which the community looks too kindly upon."

Comment: @gnat, a valid point regarding that top answer. I hope that my question has not implied that I am trying to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling them [freeloaders](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=freeloader) but it's not always that case, they might also:

- New to SO and don't understand how it works
- Got answers that wasn't helpful so they didn't accept
- Forgot to accept the answer

And perhaps for other reasons. But most important: They don't have to accept answer, it's up to them to decide on that, and there's nothing we can do about it.

We're not suppose to answer just to get reputation. You can ask them, **once**, to consider accepting an answer **if they find it helpful** (But don't instruct them to do so). And if it's important to you, you can take a look at their previous questions and figure out their accept rate, if you suspecting them for being a freeloaders then don't answer their question.

But again - That *freeloader* assumption can be dangerous and wrong, take a look at this thread (I removed the names to avoid shaming):

---

[image]

---

As you can see, the above demonstrate how an early assumption can be wrong sometimes.

Comment: Point granted. Nothing is just "black and white". My point was , as stated above, is to the fact that sometimes it is clear that they have acknowledged it was a solution, but still don't accept it. Nothing to do with chasing reputation  or anything like that as some have pointed to.

Comment: @Tempus Believe me, I've been there - But there's nothing we can really do about it. For me, an acknowledged is sometimes as good as an accepted answer/upvote (And I understand you're not after the rep), I'm happy I was able to help someone, even if they decided not to accept my answer. But I think that asking nicely to consider accepting is good because it will allow other users to know that an answer was accepted because it solved the issue