# How should I deal with this answer by a developer of the product in question?

Tags: discussion, edits, self-promotion, outsourcing, signatures

I just came upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65892284/17242583). It's certainly a good one, and solves the OP's problem (which is obvious by the comment they added under the answer, although they didn't accept it).

The question is about Spread.js by GrapeCity, and it happens that one of the GrapeCity team responded.

The problem with the answer is that it contains text such as

> I am a member of GrapeCity's Technical Engagement team

and

> Let us know if you have any questions! Best, Mackenzie

and

> Note we also attached a sample showing this to your forum question on the GrapeCity website

Should I remove those? Should I edit the language to be more generic and speak as a user unaffiliated with GrapeCity, refering to GrapeCity in the third person?

Comment: The latter should definitely be removed. The former occasionally depends on whether or not the question requires an authoritative response. In this case, I'm not convinced it adds anything and can also be removed.

Comment: It's just fluff. You have the 2k to remove it immediately. If they roll it back, flag the post as a potential edit war.

Comment: Also there was a (now deleted) comment under the answer to the question author that I _think_ was from you saying that it's "correct etiquette" to accept answers. Please don't post comments like that except potentially _once_ if the user is new and has never accepted an answer before. Which is not the case here. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251298/3270037

Comment: The _I am a member..._ bit is actually [required](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).  Quoting "The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."

Comment: @chrisneilsen Only if promoting, but they're answering a question specifically about their own software, there's no need for disclosure there. If the question wasn't related to their software and the answer suggested to use it then it would be a different matter. Perhaps you missed the bit in the question that made that quite clear: *"I've reached out to GrapeCity, developers of SpreadJS, and am awaiting a reply."*

Comment: @Nick sorry, can't aggree with you on that.  The help specifically says _Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) **happen to be about your product** or website, that’s okay. **However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers**_

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yes... Under a section labelled *"self-promotion"*, which this is blatantly not, because they're not promoting themselves, they're answering a question explicitly about them. It's like asking visual studio devs to disclose that they develop visual studio when answering questions about VS, despite them just answering a question, which we wouldn't do.

Comment: @Nick, tell you what, you delete it, I'll flag it, and we'll let the Mods decide

Comment: @nick, this is just 1 mods opinion, but the section is actually labeled *"Avoid overt self-promotion."*  And I think the text in said section, is intended to help in this regard.  So explaining how your answer maybe biased, is a really good idea to help avoid being labeled as Self Promoting.

Comment: @StephenRauch But there's no promotion here, not even slightly. The question is addressed basically directly to them. They're not recommending use of their software, they're answering a question about it. By disclosing it they're providing an authoritative reference, but by no means does it make sense for it be _required_ here.

Comment: @Nick, it is not about self promotion per se, it is about trying very hard to avoid the possible appearance of self promotion.

Comment: @StephenRauch Fair enough, although looks like what I was going for made it into the so far approved of answer: *"However, one situation where it's not strictly required is when the question itself mentions the product"*

Comment: I would put the affiliation at the end not at the beginning, personally.

Comment: The rules say you must disclose your affiliation if you're self-promoting. Do they actually say you *must not* disclose your affiliation if you aren't? It seems to me that this is very good and useful information to anyone reading this answer.

Comment: @DavidConrad there are rules against presenting things that are immaterial to the post. For example, stating you're a student, or that you work for X when that info isn't relevant to the post. But disclosing that you're an author for a tool you are answering about is certainly relevant information to the post. Not necessarily required if you're answering a question about that tool, but relevant all the same.

Comment: I put the affiliation at the end, because I think that content should come first and meta information like affiliation only afterwards.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Disclosing affiliation with the product (or company, software, etc.) mentioned in an answer is always a good idea, and in general, disclosing affiliation is *mandatory* on Stack Overflow. However, one situation where it's not strictly required is when the question itself mentions the product. In these cases, it's not considered self-promotion, and the post would not be spam even if affiliation is not disclosed.

However, mentioning the affiliation is still a good idea, since it makes any bias the answer author may have apparent to future readers. If an answer already discloses affiliation, I wouldn't remove it, as that would make the answer worse. At the very least, leaving it in doesn't do any harm.

The additional pleasantries at the end of the answer are just noise and should definitely be removed, as has already been done. Likewise for the mention of posting the sample on an external forum: that is irrelevant to the question posted on Stack Overflow, and should not be included in the answer, so I've gone ahead and removed that sentence.

Comment: Re _one situation where it's not strictly required..._ - do you have a reference for that? (Genuine question, I'd like to be sure on this)  FWIW, I don't see anything in the [_Expected Behavior_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) help or even  [_How to not be a spammer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) that suggests an exception.  Both state _you must disclose your affiliation in your answers_, with emphesis on the _must_

Comment: @chrisneilsen Actually, I only learned about this myself fairly recently as a result of participating in the [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/) project, which deals with spam content quite a lot. Here's a [message by Makyen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58778680); if you scroll down a bit, you can see the conversation, in particular [this part](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58778943) which convinced me of the merits of allowing this exception. I'm not aware of any meta post that explicitly says this though (not counting this one I just posted ;)).

Comment: "...in general, disclosing affiliation is mandatory on Stack Overflow..." Not sure about that. In general, I do not have to reveal anything about my identity here, basically posting anonymous. Only in cases of self-promotion, revealing affiliation is required. I would therefore not call it mandatory.

Comment: "Likewise for the mention of posting the sample on an external forum: that is irrelevant to the question posted on Stack Overflow, and should not be included in the answer" - if this comment would have had the link to the sample, wouldn't it be pretty much the same thing as quite common "there is a full example here", with a link to larger example? which in itself would be link-only answer but is an ok addition to otherwise full answer

Comment: The link to the forum could also be posted as a comment: not necessary for the answer, but useful if somebody wants to learn more about the issue.

Comment: I try to remember to disclose my affiliation if I make an unsolicited mention of my product, but I don't consider it necessary if the question is explicitly asking about my product. The reason for the rule is to discourage advertising or self-promotion and a factual answer to a technical question about a product is not advertising or promotion, wherever it comes from.

Comment: @Trilarion I'm not sure I follow your logic there. Disclosing affiliation *is* mandatory (except for the edge case mentioned in this answer). The fact that one could post anonymously, or otherwise hide the fact that they're affiliated, doesn't change this requirement. If it was *somehow* discovered that one had linked to some resource with which they're affiliated, without disclosure, that would be considered spam, and having posted anonymously is not an excuse for that. (It might even look worse in that case, since it might look intentional).

Comment: @eis Yes, if the answer had contained a link to the forum, and the contents of that link was in some way relevant to the post, and didn't just repeat content in the answer, leaving it in would be fine. As it stands, there was no link, and simply mentioning that there is some information somewhere else is not really helpful; it's just noise in that case, and can safely be removed.

Comment: I think people are really overthinking this. Suppose you were looking for help with whatever this question was about. And suppose you found this answer which appeared helpful. And suppose it turned out the answer was from a member of the dev team of the software. Wouldn't you want to know that? I would.

Comment: Its not about what you want or don't want. SO requires disclosure under certain circumstances. outside of that, it's up to the user.

Comment: @cigien "I'm not sure I follow your logic there." Sorry for the confusion. David Conrad says it actually better than I can below the question here: "The rules say you must disclose your affiliation if you're self-promoting. Do they actually say you must not disclose your affiliation if you aren't?". That's exactly what I wanted to say too.

Comment: @DavidConrad I absolutely agree that it's always helpful to know if the author is affiliated with the product, and I personally prefer answers that do that. There's certainly no rule that says affiliation should *not* be disclosed in any circumstances. This answer is just pointing out a situation where disclosure is not *required*. While it's a bit of an edge case, it's not really "overthinking" the issue; it's good to be clear about where the lines are drawn, as far as possible. cc Trilarion

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in this specific case, the user name of the person answering is "GrapeCity Team", and they link to the Grape City web site in their user data. While that is not an explicit disclosure, it's unavoidably a strong implicit disclosure, regardless of what is disclosed within their answer. That general approach is both prudent and helpful when answering questions about your own software: you can't be accused of non-disclosure, and readers can make an informed evaluation of the authority of your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is 100% a bad thing to post links to non-SE resources (such as forums) in an answer.  As a researcher, I don't want to hit dead ends AND I like it when there is more of a trail to follow if I am not 100% finished researching.  My opinion is that it isn't hurtful to drop a link to related content outside of SE at the bottom of the answer.  I am sure there will be users here that disagree with my opinion.

Comment: This answer makes no sense, are you going to require Jon Skeet to write a disclaimer on all joda.time answers posted over the years? [All 500 of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A22656+is%3Aa+joda)

Comment: @Braiam "A good idea" !== "This must be done 100% of the time or banned"

Comment: @KevinB A good idea isn't good if it's not generally applicable, it's a unpractical one and henceforth "not a good idea"

Comment: Someone deciding not to apply it doesn't make it not generally applicable.

Answer (score -36):

Repeat after me:

#### Disclosing affiliation when answering questions about your product makes zero sense.

We didn't require such thing with Jon Skeet when answering questions about Noda Time, we aren't going to start now. It makes no sense. If the objective is to avoid self promotion, there's zero promotion in that answer. The question is about a user of that product and someone answered without mentioning a product that is not on the question. It's not as if the user was recommending another library to solve the problem, it was recommending how the user could solve the problem they were facing with their product.

Requiring this will only make sense on a help desk situation, and I'm sure nobody wants that. Just remove the fluff and move on.

Comment: Disclosing affiliation when answering questions about your product makes zero sense.

Comment: I actually disagree wholeheartedly with this answer.  There are plenty of cases where disclosing affiliation does make sense, as described in the accepted answer and the comments beneath, despite some opinions going back and forth both ways on the matter.  Just my .02.

Comment: I agree that _requiring_ disclosure of affiliation when answering questions about a product doesn't make sense, but disclosing affiliation can nonetheless sometimes still make sense.

Comment: It makes perfect sense. The fact that the author is affiliated with the product that the question and answer are about is useful information for people who might consider either that an authoritative response is more likely to be correct, or that a response from somebody invested in a product is less likely to admit to problems with that product. Having an exception when the product is already mentioned in the question would not make sense, because those rationales don't depend on the product being introduced into the discussion by the answerer themselves.

Comment: @RyanM the later I agree, but only on certain cases, like for example: you are recommending your product as a solution to a problem. In other cases, who cares.

Comment: @kaya3 that's how you get collectives. Do you want collectives? No? Then remove the armbands.

Comment: If I am getting help from someone who is officially associated with the thing I'm asking about, I want to know that!

Comment: @DoYouEvenCodeBro and if the answer is wrong? What happens? Are you going to claim that because they are "official" they are right? Absolutely not. Then if you are going to evaluate the answer as if it was any other user, why would you care who answer it, other than if the answer is correct or not?