# Shared "team" Stack Overflow accounts

Tags: discussion, accounts

I just read the following question [How should I deal with this answer by a developer of the product in question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413087/how-should-i-deal-with-this-answer-by-a-developer-of-the-product-in-question) and noticed that the question in question (hehe) has been answered by what appears to be a *team account* rather than a personal account:

[image: Screenshot top part]

...

[image: Screenshot bottom part]

Of course, I have no *proof* that this account is actually used by multiple people---the "technical engagement team" might have only one member, or each member might have their own account with just the same user name.

In fact, I don't really care about this particular case, but it raises an interesting, general question: Are we OK with accounts being used by multiple people? Do we expect the "reputation system" (build up reputation, get more privileges) to work not only with individual people but also with *groups* of people?

(I don't have a personal opinion on this. I'm just curious on whether this has been thought of and whether there is an official guideline on that.)