# How to get a response marked as answered when the question author has low reputation score

Tags: discussion

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77805325/how-can-we-implement-autocomplete-with-api-and-multi-select-in-react-querybuilde/77814075) a while back and the poster agreed it should be marked as the answer, but they have too low a reputation score to mark it. Is there some way to get it marked as the answer by another user?

Comment: You really [shouldn't even try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on/417578#417578)

Comment: The OP of that question has now accepted the answer, so my hunch about them having mistaken the upvote button for the accept button was likely correct.

Comment: *"Is there some way to get it marked as the answer by another user"* - this question is a red flag because if you knew how the acceptance feature works, you would know the answer is a hard no. I [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) from the documentation: *"As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem."* . Key bits: *"As the asker"* and *"may"*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [create posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts) privileges page, requiring 1 reputation:

> ## create posts
>
> Creation privilege awarded at 1 reputation
>
> […]
>
> When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you're getting value from the community.

So reputation is not preventing OP from accepting your answer.

Comment: I wonder whether the OP of that question has gotten confused between accepting an answer (which doesn't require rep) and upvoting an answer (which does). They may have tried to accept the answer by clicking the upvote button and not realised their mistake.